# How do I iterate through nested comments in PHP?

Tags: php

I have the basic styling down, and I have the database for the comments created... but now I don't know how to get these comments and iterate through them. So the table contains the comments id, content, authors id, and a comment parent id.

How would I iterate through the comments and the replies to print them out so it's like:

```
comment
- reply
-- reply to reply
- reply
-- reply to reply

comment
-reply
-- reply to reply
-- reply to reply
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion.

It should look like this.
You have a function which is named `showReplies($replies);` which renders the comment/reply box.

```
showReplies($replies){
    if (count($replies) == 0){ return; } // stop if no replies need to be printed out
    foreach ($replies as $reply){
        echo $reply->text.'<br>'; // show reply text
        showReplies($reply->childReplies); // continue showing the child replies
    }
}
```